# Postgres: Count occurences of integer in an array in a result set

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I am trying to count the number of of occurences of integers in an array for each record.

My table is this:

| customerid | groups |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {324,299,523,534,565,212} |
| 2 | {324,299,523,534,565,212} |
| 3 | {324} |
| 4 | {324,299,523,212} |

I would like to return the following:

| groupid | count |
| --- | --- |
| 324 | 4 |
| 299 | 3 |
| 523 | 3 |

etc

I have tried looping through the cursor and storing count in map but I would like something more performant.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
  groupid,
  count(*)
  from (
    select unnest(groups) as groupid
    from table_name
  ) data
group by groupid
order by count desc
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `unnest`:

```
select unnest(groups) groupid
       ,count(*) count
from customergroups 
group by groupid
order by count desc
```